# What's wrong in this C program that finds the largest of 4 given numbers

Tags: c

I've wrote a simple C program that finds the largest of 4 numbers. I'm trying all the possible combination of 4 digits number which currently limits to 1234.

Due to some repeated formatting error while writing this question, I've posted my code to some other site.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf("Input A, B, C and D: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    if(a > b) {
        if(a > c) {
            if(a > d) {
                printf("A is greater.");
            } else {
                printf("D is greater.");
            }
        }
    } else if(b > c) {
        if(b > d) {
            printf("B is greater.");
        } else {
            printf("D is greater.");
        }
    } else if(c > d) {
        printf("C is greater.");
    } else printf("D is greater");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work with

```
a = 2

b = 1

c = 3

d = 4
```

and

```
a = 2

b = 1

c = 4

d = 3
```

Is there anything wrong in my implementation? And I'm currently trying to use as minimum comparison as possible (6 minimum possible comparison for ABCD) like a>b, b>c, c>d etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Links are frowned upon around here. The link *will* go stale, and the question becomes useless. Besides, I hate clicking through links.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a link to a program and some questions.

Comment: Where's `else` for `if(a > c)`?

Comment: I'd suggest you draw a flowchart first of what you've done when more if and elses are included and then it's easy to track what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is if A is bigger then B but lesser than C.

```
if(a > b) {
    if(a > c) {
        if(a > d) {
            printf("A is greater.");
        } else {
            printf("D is greater.");
        }
    } else if(c > d) {
        printf("C is greater.");
    } else {
        printf("D is greater");
    }
}
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: Still doesn't work @Asthor. Can you please provide me a working code?

Comment: @user3390055 Fairly certain I shouldn't as it should be easy enough to solve but did anyway.